# Get interval from DatePeriod variable

Tags: php, php-5.3

As I understood from PHP manual page for [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class that it is purposed to store periods of time. I.e. interval with some point at time meaning start of the interval + optional recurrences.

With the following code I create $dp variable starting today with length of one month

```
$start = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$end = clone $start;
$end->add($interval);    
$dp = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
```

With following code I am printing all (at my example only one cause there are no recurrences) start dates of the period:

```
foreach ($dp as $d)
    var_dump($d->d);
```

My question is how can I get interval from $dp variable?

Comment: Is it me or is `DatePeriod` very badly documented? I see a `format` method in the examples that isn't in the docs

Comment: @Pekka it's you. DatePeriod returns DateTimel elements when iterating it, so it's DateTime::format() you are refering to ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot because [`DatePeriod` does not expose any properties](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53439). If you need the Interval, reuse it from your `$interval` variable.

Comment: It's sad because now DatePeriod is no more than collection of DateTime objects automatically generated when I call DatePeriod constructor (

Comment: @Boffin yes, that's actually what it is :)

Comment: @Boffin: Why does it need to be anything more than that?  What were you hoping for?  I've never tried to do so, so I don't know if it's even possible, but you could try extending the class and overriding the constructor to save the interval and expose it through a getter method.  It may not be possible to extend it though.